# How to get duplicates DataColumns from a List Collection C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates

I have a list of DataColumns where some of them have the same extended property value. How can I get a new list only with all of them which have the same extended property value?

```
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("col1", typeof(string));
            col.ExtendedProperties.Add("Common-Value", "AAA");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("col2", typeof(string));
            col.ExtendedProperties.Add("Common-Value", "BBB");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("col3", typeof(string));
            col.ExtendedProperties.Add("Common-Value", "CCC");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("col4", typeof(string));
            col.ExtendedProperties.Add("Common-Value", "AAA");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("col1", typeof(string));
            col.ExtendedProperties.Add("Common-Value", "DDD");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("col1", typeof(string));
            col.ExtendedProperties.Add("Common-Value", "AAA");
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
```

I want a new list of DataColumn with all the DataColumn with Common-Value = "AAA". In this example Count = 3

I tried this code but I hope this don't work for this.

```
var duplicates = colDataColumns.GroupBy(col => col).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see groups which have more than one item with a matching Common-Value:

```
var groupsWithDuplicates = colDataColumns.GroupBy(col =>
      col.ExtendedProperties["Common-Value"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

To get just the items from those groups, add a [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx), and you can do a `ToList` if you want.

```
List<DataColumn> groupsWithDuplicates = colDataColumns.GroupBy(col =>
      col.ExtendedProperties["Common-Value"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
          .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to work. At the end I add .ToList() to assign it to a new List but it's giving me NULL. You know why? I'm trying the first method in order to do it generic. I realized the List is correct.

Comment: I don't see any way that `ToList()` can return `null`. Do you mean that the list is empty, because no such groups were found, or maybe that you're getting a null-related exception?

Comment: Yes you are right sorry. The list is empty and not null! But it's so weird I see the values are correct.

Comment: I found the problem. I don't know why but if you do col.ExtendedProperties["Common-Value"].ToString(). It works. Thanks but it's returning just 1 element. Can I have all the repeated ones individually and not group by? and of a type specific like List<x> at design time and no runtime?

Comment: @MaximusDecimus I've added it to my answer: `SelectMany` is the key. And C#'s `var` is still statically-typed at compile time, not a runtime thing. It just means "hey, compiler, you figure out the type".